# getting error: 'tuple' object has no attribute width' when creating qr scanner

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know, there was answers, but I am new to python, and don't understand how to fix the problem.

I was creating QR Code scanner and I copy code from:
https://pastebin.com/C4r2uNCC

And I get these errors.
I have Webcam plugged in. That's not the problem.

```
[ 2076.921537] usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0 Camera
[ 2077.018998] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Author : Jimmyromanticdevil
# QRbar-cv
#
# Proc of consept :
# this is just simple code from part of my work for QRcode & Barcode scanner with webcame stuff
# i am using Opencv for realtime track the image & zbar for decode the image
#
# Dependency :
#
#
# Some of Good Refrensi stuff :
#   https://github.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV
#   http://nwlinux.com/install-qtqr-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-using-apt-get/
#   http://zbar.sourceforge.net/

import cv2 as cv  # Use OpenCV-2.4.3
import zbar


def scanner_procces(frame, set_zbar):
    set_width = 100.0 / 100
    set_height = 90.0 / 100

    coord_x = int(frame.width * (1 - set_width) / 2)
    coord_y = int(frame.height * (1 - set_height) / 2)
    width = int(frame.width * set_width)
    height = int(frame.height * set_height)

    get_sub = cv.GetSubRect(frame, (coord_x + 1, coord_y + 1, width - 1, height - 1))

    cv.Rectangle(frame, (coord_x, coord_y), (coord_x + width, coord_y + height), (255, 0, 0))

    cm_im = cv.CreateImage((get_sub.width, get_sub.height), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
    cv.ConvertImage(get_sub, cm_im)
    image = zbar.Image(cm_im.width, cm_im.height, 'Y800', cm_im.tostring())

    set_zbar.scan(image)
    for symbol in image:
        print()
        '\033[1;32mResult : %s symbol "%s" \033[1;m' % (symbol.type, symbol.data)

    cv.ShowImage("QR Koodi Skanneri", frame)
    # cv.ShowImage("webcame2", get_sub)
    cv.WaitKey(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # set up our stuff
    cv.namedWindow("QR Koodi Scanneri", cv.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    capture = cv.VideoCapture(-1)
    set_zbar = zbar.ImageScanner()
    while True:
        frame = capture.read()
        scanner_procces(frame, set_zbar)
```

And Logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kassakone_scanner.py", line 56, in <module>
    scanner_procces(frame, set_zbar)
  File "kassakone_scanner.py", line 26, in scanner_procces
    coord_x = int(frame.width * (1 - set_width) / 2)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'width'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a tuple, which means it has index-bassed assignment of values. To refer to a length in a tuple(length,width) you simply access the index [0].

Comment: Can you post code, then I understand how to fix it.

Comment: Use `frame[0] and frame[1]` instead of `frame.width and frame.height`. If the tuples are stored as (width,height) pairs.

Comment: Now I get error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kassakone_scanner.py", line 56, in <module>
    scanner_procces(frame, set_zbar)
  File "kassakone_scanner.py", line 27, in scanner_procces
    coord_y = int(frame[1] * (1 - set_height) / 2)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars @S Vengat

Comment: How Can I fix it? @SVengat